# Java: How to Exclude Implicit Import of java.lang classes

Tags: java

If I wanted to exclude loading java.lang.String, for example, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: why do you want to do that? I can't think of a reason.

Comment: I do not think this can be done, however I also dont think that this would be a good idea

Comment: i don't think its possible. the question is why do you want to do that? what do you want to achieve by that? what else did you try before that didn't work?

Comment: I'd imagine not loading such classes would make sense for embedded situations (slow processors, memory constraints).

Comment: in that case, look into Java9 / project jigsaw

Comment: includes are processed at compile time, so it doesn't make sense to exclude a package for performance reasons. Plus, whatever JVM you're running on is still going to know about java.lang.String.

Comment: Why the down-votes? Just because it's not a good idea doesn't mean it's not okay to ask.

Comment: The tooltip for downvotes reads: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear **or not useful**."

Answer (score 6):

Write your own compiler, that can compile this new, almost-Java language.

In [Java,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-7.html)

> Code in a compilation unit automatically has access to all types declared in its package and also automatically imports all of the public types declared in the predefined package `java.lang`.

There is no way to disable that behavior. And you don't need to; imports only affect compilation, and even if a type was (unwisely) named the same as a `java.lang` type, like `Object`, you can reference it with its fully qualified name in source code.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up two topics.

The heading reads "How to Exclude Implicit Import of java.lang classes", and in the body you ask about "exclude loading java.lang.String".

The automatic import of `java.lang.*` has **no influence whatsoever** on the runtime. It only allows you at compile-time to reference strings with the simple word `String` instead of the dot-construct `java.lang.String`.

The class `java.lang.String` will be **loaded if and only if your code needs it**, no matter if you referenced it as `String` or as `java.lang.String` in your source code.

And I am VERY SURE that every Java program needs the String class, e.g. in its `public static void main(String[] args)` plus in lots of library classes.

So, if you worry about memory footprint so much that loading the String class might become a problem, switch to a different language, e.g. K&R C from the 1970s.